# Find Closest Route from single source to several different destinations in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, routing

I've made network nodes in PostgreSQL SQL based on Osm2po. I can find the closest way among two points based on the pgr_dikstra algorithm but I want to find the closest route between **one single source point** and **several destination points** just in one query and **choose the closest one**. How can I implement this query? For example, suppose I want to find the closest vehicle to me when there are many available vehicles

This is my code

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT gid as id, source, target, length_m AS cost FROM ' || $1,
        -- source
        (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr
            ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x1,y1),4326) LIMIT 1),
        -- target
        (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr
            ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(x2,y2),4326) LIMIT 1),
        false)
```

but this code works just for two points

Answer (score 1):

Read the [docs](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#pgr-dijkstra) carefully: `pgr_Dijkstra` has multiple signatures, and one of them runs the [*one-to-many*](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/pgr_dijkstra.html#pgr-dijkstra-one-to-many) routing you are looking for.

You simply pass in all your target nodes as `ARRAY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pgr_Dijkstra(
         'SELECT gid as id, source, target, length_m AS cost FROM ' || $1,
         <src_id>,
         ARRAY[<tgt_id>, <tgt_id>, ...],
         FALSE
       )
;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

And I should read you question carefully; to actually get *only those rows that belong to the shortest path*, run

```
WITH
    paths AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   pgr_Dijkstra(
                 'SELECT gid as id, source, target, length_m AS cost FROM ' || $1,
                 <src_id>,
                 ARRAY[<tgt_id>, <tgt_id>, ...],
                 FALSE
               )
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    paths
WHERE   end_vid = (
    SELECT  end_vid
    FROM    paths
    GROUP BY
            end_vid
    ORDER BY
            MAX(agg_cost)
    LIMIT   1
);
```

Comment: tnx for the response but I need something like this: ARRAY[ (lat,lng),(lat,lng),(lat,lng),...]

Comment: you know what  i wanna send pairs of lat ,lng in array

Comment: @hamed you will likely need to wrap the conversion between your coordinate pairs and nodes of the graph into a function, as you are presumably already trying to do; is the real question here **how to match your coordinate pairs to the network topology?**